# Command to check the count of total admin group members in windows

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to only see the count of users in numbers, or even the user names (`Administrator, User10998`) from above output in Windows Server 2019 PowerShell.

```
PS C:\>net localgroup administrators

Alias name     administrators
Comment        Administrators have complete and unrestricted access to the computer/domain

Members

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Administrator
User10998
The command completed successfully.
```

Comment: I would definitly use `Get-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators"` but if you still want to use `net localgroup administrators`, i guess the better option is to use a regex to only have the names maybe try something like that `$administrators = (net localgroup administrators) -match "^-+$|^$|The command completed successfully" -notmatch "Comment|^$"`. (I have my powershell in French so i cant verify if its working)

Comment: @su7 You should post this as answer so the OP can accept. Otherwise, this will remain an 'unanswered' question..

Answer (score 1):

First option is to use :

`Get-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators"`

Second option is to use a regex to filter only the name of the users (based on your command):

```
$administrators = (net localgroup administrators) -match "^-+$|^$|The command completed successfully" -notmatch "Comment|^$".
```

If you want to replicate it for other commands; https://regex101.com/ is a useful site that allows you to learn how to use regex

Answer (score 0):

Since you also tagged the question with bash, this is how to do this in `bash` under Windows (e.g. using the bash provided by the Windows Subsystem for Linux).

1. Show the admin users

`net.exe localgroup administrators | sed -n '/---/,/successfully/{//!p}'`

2. Show the number of admin users

`net.exe localgroup administrators | sed -n '/---/,/successfully/{//!p}' | wc -l`

*(Either works in cmd.exe as well really, you just need `sed` and `wc` as provided e.g. by [Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/))*

Comment: Just wanted a powershell command to run to get the expected output. Due to limitations on the server, we can't install anything.